# extract greater than 4 digit numbers from a string php regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

```
preg_match_all('/(\d{4})/', $text, $matches);
```

Using above function we can extract exact 4 digit numbers from a given string.

How can extract the numbers that contains greater than 4 digits using regular expression..

Is there any way to specify the minimum length in regular expressions ?

Comment: Try preg_match_all('/(\d{4,})/', $text, $matches); Is it working?

Comment: This is very helpful when it comes to remove telephone numbers from a string with PHP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can specify the minimum length:

```
/(\d{4,})/
```

The brace syntax accepts a single number (as you used) indicating the exact number of repetitions to match, but it also allows specifying the minimum and maximum number of repetitions to match, separated by a comma. If the maximum is omitted (but the comma isn't), as in this answer, then the maximum is unbounded. The minimum can also be omitted, which is the same as explicitly specifying a minimum of 0.

Comment: yes working fine.Also preg_match_all('/(\d{4,})/', $text, $matches);
$matches returns 2 arrays contains same result.Please guide me.

Comment: @Muthu: Sorry, I don't know PHP (just regexes). Ask another question ;-)

Comment: The first element in the array is the full match, the second is the match in the parenthesis (first capture). Remove the parenthesis for a single element in the array, or use either index.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want something like this:

```
\d{4,}
```

So:

```
preg_match_all('#(\d{4,})#', $text, $matches);
```

Note that I used `#` as the delimiter here, I find it easier to look at :)

Comment: it separates all the numbers into 4 chars

Answer (score 1):

\d{4,}

Should do it. This sets 4 to minimum.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all('/(\d{4,})/', $text, $matches);
```